# Stock Market API Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http

I am somewhat new to Node.JS, looking for some insight on how I can utilize the information that is being provided by another person's API. For example.

**Heres the API I would like to use**
http://live-nse.herokuapp.com/?symbol=AMAR
*The source code can be found at https://github.com/ashwanthkumar/Live-NSE-Stock*

Im really interested in how I can use this information, for example, if you use that link to get the statistics for the symbol AMAR, it responds with JSON i believe? (Please correct me if im wrong).

Here is an example response it gives.

```
{"lastUpdateTime":"03-NOV-2013 19:50:03","tradedDate":"03NOV2013","data":[{"extremeLossMargin":"-","cm_ffm":"15.47","bcStartDate":"19-DEC-12","change":"0.35","buyQuantity3":"200","sellPrice1":"-","buyQuantity4":"181","sellPrice2":"-","priceBand":"5","buyQuantity1":"530","deliveryQuantity":"-","buyQuantity2":"1","cm_adj_low":"6.00","sellPrice5":"-","quantityTraded":"-","buyQuantity5":"1,000","sellPrice3":"-","sellPrice4":"-","open":"7.55","cm_adj_high":"48.20","low52":"6.00","securityVar":"-","marketType":"N","pricebandupper":"8.25","totalTradedValue":"0.11","faceValue":"10.00","ndStartDate":"-","previousClose":"7.55","symbol":"AMAR","varMargin":"100.00","lastPrice":"7.90","pChange":"4.64","adhocMargin":"-","companyName":"Amar Remedies Limited","averagePrice":"7.78","secDate":"-","series":"BE","isinCode":"INE787G01011","indexVar":"-","pricebandlower":"7.55","totalBuyQuantity":"2,113","high52":"48.20","purpose":"ANNUAL GENERAL MEETING","cm_adj_low_dt":"28-JUN-13","closePrice":"7.90","recordDate":"-","cm_adj_high_dt":"08-JAN-13","totalSellQuantity":"-","dayHigh":"7.90","exDate":"17-DEC-12","sellQuantity5":"-","bcEndDate":"26-DEC-12","ndEndDate":"-","sellQuantity2":"-","sellQuantity1":"-","buyPrice1":"7.85","sellQuantity4":"-","buyPrice2":"7.40","sellQuantity3":"-","applicableMargin":"100.00","buyPrice4":"7.30","buyPrice3":"7.35","buyPrice5":"7.25","dayLow":"7.55","deliveryToTradedQuantity":"-","totalTradedVolume":"1,352"}]}
```

I would like to know how I can get my Node.JS app to receive this information. And could I set this to a VAR so i could quote it wherever I would like later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a request like this :

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'live-nse.herokuapp.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/?symbol=AMAR'
};

http.get(options, function(res){
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  var data="";
  res.on('data', function(chunk){
    data += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function(){
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  //do whatever with obj
  });
});
```